# Font-face webfont is not working in mobile size

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have use this webfont in my website. In CSS it shown like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'PF-Tempesta-Seven-Compressed';
    src:url('fonts/PF-Tempesta-Seven-Compressed.ttf.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/PF-Tempesta-Seven-Compressed.ttf.svg#PF-Tempesta-Seven-Compressed') format('svg'),
        url('fonts/PF-Tempesta-Seven-Compressed.ttf.eot'),
        url('fonts/PF-Tempesta-Seven-Compressed.ttf.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'); 
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

It is linked in the following:

```
h1 {
padding-left:5px;
font-family:'PF-Tempesta-Seven-Compressed';
font-size:14px;
color: #4b4848;
background:#f3e600;
}
```

It works when the page size is bigger than 480px, but does not work when smaller than 480px. How is this possible...?

Comment: That is weird indeed, do you have a live site we can see?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle I made to show what I got for now. https://jsfiddle.net/swn6cr6b/